# Accessing to gitlab docker container outputs connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have a docker container running this configuration for the gitlab-ce image:

```
version: "3"
services:
  gitlab:
   hostname: gitlab.mydomain.com
   image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
   container_name: gitlab
   restart: always
   ports:
     - 3000:80
   volumes:
     - /opt/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
     - /opt/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
     - /opt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: custom_network
```

When running docker ps i see my container up and running with the 80 container port mapped to the 3000 host machine port as intended.

Altough when running : `wget -O- https://172.25.0.2:3000` i am getting this error message:
`Connecting to 172.25.0.2:3000... failed: Connection refused.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map a port, you should use the host IPs to access through the mapped port.

So if you need to access port `80` use the container IP.
If you need to access port `3000` use the host IP or localhost of the main host itself or even if you have a private interface inside your host.

So this command: `wget -O- https://172.25.0.2:3000` means that you are talking to the container directly not through the mapped port and requesting a service listening on port 3000 which is not true so the result will be connection refused.

Comment: Alright i get it. Now i want to use this docker container along with an nginx reverse proxy container. They are on the same custom_network. This error still occures.

Comment: Which error?  Your question does not explain anything related to this. Please modify the question with the problem you have or post another question with your problem

Comment: I'm sorry i was actually updating the comment. In my reverse_proxy configuration, should i tell it to proxy_pass to http://localhost:3000 ? (they are on the same network)

Comment: No, any container should connect to the other container which inside the same network with the service name which will be `gitlab` in your case and the port will be 80 so nginx will reverse to `http://gitlab:80`